# Does JQuery's Ajax refer to maxJsonLength property in web.config

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, web-config

In my ASP.NET site, I use Jquery AJAX to load json data (in fact a string) from a webservice when clicking the search button :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(parameterArray),
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    d = JSON.parse(response.d);
  }
```

When the return string gets too big, the page stop responding. I have to go to `web.config` and add this property in order for the website to work :

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
```

Here is how do the application handle the `search result` before returning data to the browser :

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
string strData = dService.searhforData(ipt);
List<Dictionary<string, object>> lRow = processData(strData);
string r = serializer.Serialize(lRow);
return r;
```

In case the Json string got too long, the page just stop responding,  there wasn't any error in the console window. As I debug at the .Net application side, the `serializer.Serialize(lRow);` went smoothly and successfully return the `r`, after that, the loading icon on the page just keep spinning. If I press F5 on the page, the search data appears.

My question is, if `JQuery's Ajax` refers to the `web.config` for the max json string length, why couldn't I find any information regarding this on the internet ?

Comment: No, it absolutely doesn't. It seems a .net related configuration instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there is a limit on the amount of data that `JSON.parse()` can handle, but that's not related to your problem.

Your `web.config` file holds settings to be used *server side*. The JS on the client is not related to that at all. If you needed to amend that setting it's because your ASP.Net code was producing a JSON response longer than was previously allowed by the default setting of `jsonSerialization`.

If you checked the browser console after making the failed request you would most likely have seen an error in the response which guided you to the problem.

Comment: Emphasis on _"default setting"_

Comment: but there wasnt any error in the console window, It just stops responding, and if I pressed F5, the result appear instead of 'normal page refresh'

Comment: It wasn't a dumb question at all. Glad you got it solved.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks. Only one more question, if I changed the `dataType ` to `text`, it is supposed to go smoothly right? But the page still not responding.

Comment: The data format only affects the way the response is decoded. It wouldn't inherently make anything 'go smoothly' if it was already working. I'd suggest starting a new question if you have problems - but be sure to check the console and report on any errors you find in there